# Finding height in binary search tree after insertions and deletions

Tags: c, tree, binary-search-tree

The code below is supposed to output the final height of a binary search tree after a series of insertions and deletions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
};

struct Node* Insert(int data, struct Node *root){
    if(root == NULL){
        root = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        root -> data = data;
        root -> left = root -> right = NULL;
    }
    else{
        if(data < root -> data) Insert(data, root -> left);
        else if(data > root -> data) Insert(data, root -> left);
    }
    return root;
}

struct Node* Find(int data, struct Node *root){
    if(root == NULL || root -> data == data) return root;
    if(data < root -> data) return Find(data, root -> left);
    if(data > root -> data) return Find(data, root -> right);
}

int FindMin(struct Node *root){
    int min, l_min, r_min;
    if(root == NULL) return INT_MIN;
    min = root -> data;
    l_min = FindMin(root -> left);
    r_min = FindMin(root -> right);
    if( l_min  < min ) min = l_min;
    if( r_min < min  ) min = r_min;
    return min;
}

struct Node* Delete(int data, struct Node *root){
    struct Node *temp;
    if(data < root -> data) root -> left = Delete(data, root -> left);
    else if(data > root -> data) root -> right = Delete(data, root -> right);
    else{
        if(root -> left != NULL && root -> right != NULL){
            root -> data = FindMin(root -> right);
            root -> right = Delete(root -> data, root -> right);
        }
        else{
            temp = root;
            if(root -> left == NULL) root = root -> right;
            if(root -> right == NULL) root = root -> left;
            free(temp);
        }
    }
    return root;
}

int Height(struct Node *root){
    int l_height, r_height;
    if(root == NULL) return 0;
    else{
        l_height = Height(root -> left);
        r_height = Height(root -> right);
        if(l_height > r_height) return l_height + 1;
        else return r_height + 1;
    }
}

int main(){
    struct Node *root = NULL, *temp = NULL;
    int n, a, b;
    scanf("%i",&n);
    while(n--){
        scanf("%i %i",&a,&b);
        if(a == 1){
            temp = Find(b,root);
            if(temp != NULL) continue;
            root = Insert(b,root);
        }
        else if(a == 2){
            temp = Find(b,root);
            if(temp == NULL) continue;
            root = Delete(b,root);
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }
    printf("Height: %i\n",Height(root));
    return 0;
}
```

First input is number n which is the number of lines to follow.

All following lines have the integers "a b". a == 1 means insertion and b == 2 means deletion, and b is the value to be inserted or deleted.  The "Find" function tests if a value exists on the BST so that I don't insert things that already exist or try to remove things that do not exist on the BST.

So, for instance, this is a valid test case, and it should return 5:

```
10
1 5
1 8
1 3
1 4
1 2
1 1
1 0
1 7
1 9
2 3
```

However, my code is failing to do so and is simply returning "1" for every possible test case. I have no clue why this is happening. Any ideas?

**Solution**: Thanks to @coderredoc , here's now a fully functioning version of this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>


struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
};

struct Node* Insert(int data, struct Node *root){
    if(root == NULL){
        root = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        root -> data = data;
        root -> left = root -> right = NULL;
    }
    else{
        if(data < root -> data) root -> left = Insert(data, root -> left);
        else if(data > root -> data) root -> right = Insert(data, root -> right);
    }
    return root;
}

struct Node* Find(int data, struct Node *root){
    if(root == NULL || root -> data == data) return root;
    if(data < root -> data) return Find(data, root -> left);
    if(data >= root -> data) return Find(data, root -> right);
    return NULL;
}

struct Node* FindMin(struct Node *root){
    struct Node *temp = root;
    while( temp -> left != NULL) temp = temp -> left;
    return temp;
}

struct Node* Delete(int data, struct Node *root){
    struct Node *temp;
    if(root == NULL) return NULL;
    if(data < root -> data) root -> left = Delete(data, root -> left);
    else if(data > root -> data) root -> right = Delete(data, root -> right);
    else{
        if(root -> left == NULL){
            temp = root -> right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else if(root -> right == NULL){
            temp = root -> left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else{
            temp = FindMin(root -> right);
            root -> data = temp -> data;
            root -> right = Delete( temp -> data, root -> right);
        }
    }
    return root;
}

int Height(struct Node *root){
    int l_height, r_height;
    if(root == NULL) return 0;
    else{
        l_height = Height(root -> left);
        r_height = Height(root -> right);
        if(l_height > r_height) return l_height + 1;
        else return r_height + 1;
    }
}

int main(){
    struct Node *root = NULL, *temp = NULL;
    int n, a, b;
    scanf("%i",&n);
    while(n--){
        scanf("%i %i",&a,&b);
        if(a == 1){
            temp = Find(b,root);
            if(temp != NULL) continue;
            root = Insert(b,root);
        }
        else if(a == 2){
            temp = Find(b,root);
            if(temp == NULL) continue;
            root = Delete(b,root);
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }
    printf("%i\n",Height(root));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's because you never linked any added node.

```
if(data < root -> data) root->left= Insert(data, root -> left);
else if(data >= root -> data) root->right = Insert(data, root -> right);
```

Also note that in both the cases in `Insert()` you had used `root->left`. It should be as shown above.

Also in the `Find()` function

```
struct Node* Find(int data, struct Node *root){
    if(root == NULL || root -> data == data) return root;
    if(data < root -> data) return Find(data, root -> left);
    if(data >= root -> data) return Find(data, root -> right);
    //      ^   You need to make it >=
    return NULL; //<----Add it
}
```

Also the seg fault you got is because of the wrong delete logic. The correct one would be like

```
struct Node* Delete(int data, struct Node *root){
    struct Node *temp;
    if( root == NULL) return NULL;
    if(data < root -> data) root -> left = Delete(data, root -> left);
    else if(data > root -> data) root -> right = Delete(data, root -> right);
    else{
        if (root->left == NULL)
        {
            struct Node *temp = root->right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else if (root->right == NULL)
        {
            struct Node *temp = root->left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else
        {
            struct Node *temp = FindMin(root->right);
            root->data = temp->data;
            root->right = Delete( temp->data, root->right);
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Also your version of `findMin` just returns the minimum value of all the node values. But this is not what is needed in `Delete()` function. That's why this function.

```
struct Node*FindMin(struct Node* node)
{
    struct Node *current = node;
    while (current->left != NULL)
            current = current->left;
    return current;
}
```

Comment: Did you test this? I get segmentation fault on these lines if I do this on my code.

Comment: @Ruan.: Even with your code it will work..sorry for the late reply. But you need to make the changes like this because otherwise you were not assigning it. And return `NULL` in `Find()`. I have added another way to add a node but yes you can do it like this also.

Comment: @Ruan.: With these changes this code works properly and for your given set of input it outputs `5`. If you only check the insertion and check the height out it would work.